# How do I convert my current non PKCE token exchange workflow to PKCE?

Tags: reactjs, oauth, jwt, amazon-cognito, pkce

I'm using cognito to exchange the code with a valid jwt and this is what my workflow looks like:

1. user visits the cognito auth page:
   `https://{SOME APP}.us-west-2.amazoncognito.com/login?client_id={CLIENT_ID}&response_type=code&scope=openid&redirect_uri=https://{MYAPP}`
2. The user gets redirected to my app's `https://{MYAPP}/#/token?code={CODE}` route
3. The following code gets executed and exchanges for a valid jwt.

   ```
   componentDidMount() {
        const parsed = queryString.parse(location.hash);
        const code = parsed["/token?code"]
        const credential = btoa(`${OAUTH_CLIENT_ID}:${OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET}`)
        const headers = {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "authorizationMethod": "body",
            "Authorization": `Basic ${credential}`
        }
        if (typeof code === "string") {
            let requestBody = new URLSearchParams({
                grant_type: 'authorization_code',
                code: code,
                client_id: OAUTH_CLIENT_ID,
                redirect_uri: OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI
            }).toString();
            const requestOptions = {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: headers,
                body: requestBody
            };
            fetch(OAUTH_TOKEN_EXCHANGE_URL, requestOptions)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then((result) => {
                    jsonWebToken = result
                    console.log(jsonWebToken)
                    // TODO redirect to another page after this
                })
        }
    }
   ```

The problem with this is that I'm not using PKCE workflow which exposes the client secret. So I altered it to this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    //user visits https://{SOME APP}.us-west-2.amazoncognito.com/login?client_id={CLIENT_ID}&response_type=code&scope=openid&redirect_uri=https://{MYAPP}&code_challenge=M2ZlZDlhODhlNTY4YjM4MTEwNTYwZTZmZTdhOGI4YmMyYmRhMmEzNGIyYjIxOGM2NDFiYzI4MDUwMWY4MDg3Nw%3D%3D&code_challenge_method=S256
    const code_verifier =  '5336dbab1ac92a20770ae00ab20a9eb391646d4786a56dad310e6ba6' //generateCodeVerifier();
    const code_challenge =  'M2ZlZDlhODhlNTY4YjM4MTEwNTYwZTZmZTdhOGI4YmMyYmRhMmEzNGIyYjIxOGM2NDFiYzI4MDUwMWY4MDg3Nw%3D%3D' //generateCodeChallengeFromVerifier(code_verifier);


    const parsed = queryString.parse(location.hash);
    const code = parsed["/token?code"]
    const headers = {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "authorizationMethod": "body",
    }
    if (typeof code === "string" && typeof code_verifier === "string") {
        let requestBody = new URLSearchParams({
            grant_type: 'authorization_code',
            code: code,
            client_id: OAUTH_CLIENT_ID,
            code_verifier: code_verifier,
            redirect_uri: OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI
        }).toString();
        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: headers,
            body: requestBody
        };
        fetch(OAUTH_TOKEN_EXCHANGE_URL, requestOptions)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then((result) => {
                jsonWebToken = result
                console.log(jsonWebToken)
                // TODO redirect to another page after this
            })
    }

}
```

Code verifier is just the raw string, and the code challenge I took the code verifier and hashed it with sha256, encoded it in base64, and then URL encoded it.

But I'm getting a very non descriptive error of: "Invalid Request". How do I go about debugging this or converting this? I've hard coded the code verifier and the code challenge for the purposes of testing but it doesn't seem to be making this easy.